# AWS ELB Logging to S3 with X-Forwarded-For as Client IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elb, x-forwarded-for

We have a DDoS layer (Project Shield) that forwards public requests to our AWS Application Load Balancer (ALB). Our ALB is has access logging enabled (to an S3 Bucket). Outside of setting up the bucket, setting permissions and enabling this feature, I haven't found many configuration options.

It appears the ALB logs store the Client IP as Project Shield (vs. the IP listed in the X-Forwarded-For header). Is it possible to have the ALB record the original client ip (left-most in X-Forwarded-For)?

If this is not possible, perhaps there is a better solution that I'm overlooking.

My goal is to have our firewall setup parse through these logs, washing them against rules and blacklisting IPs based on malicious traffic/patterns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seem to be some issues with what you are proposing.  Among them... Project Shield is also a cache, isn't it?  So the `X-Forwarded-For` value has limited meaning -- you should only see requests that are cache misses, and with popular content, that should be a minority of requests.  Assuming you had addresses you wanted to block, your firewall rules can't block any addresses you discover, because your firewall will see the back-side addresses of the Project Shield servers as the source of the traffic, not the original client.

Comment: Also, note that the original client IP is **not** the leftmost address in `X-Forwarded-For`.  The only value you can assume to be the original client IP is the *rightmost untrusted address* in `X-Forwarded-For`.  Commonly this is also the leftmost but that is not a consistently-valid approach, because the client can trivially spoof the leftmost value, or any value except the value that was added by the rightmost trusted device in the chain -- which is always the rightmost untrusted address in the list.

Comment: Thank you @Michael-sqlbot - You are correct on both counts.I was thinking I could have the ip address logged and then the request blocked by the firewall if the originating ip was in a blacklist. However, those requests would still hit Shield and Shield would still attempt to pull the misses. Thank you for the thorough response. -Shaun